# Changing some bars colors

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to change the colors bar in matplotlib for the last colors to be blue. But in the end they are all green.

```
colors = ['blue' if (i>=19 and i<23) else 'green' for i in 

list(range(24))]
df.plot(y='Jan',kind='bar',edgecolor='none',figsize=(16,8),linewidth=2, color=colors)
plt.legend(prop={'size':16})

ax = plt.gca()
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
ax.set_xticklabels(df.index)



plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('myimage.svg', format='svg', dpi=1200)   

plt.show()
```

what am I missing? I followed similar tutorials

Here is some data to test the example

```
sales = [('Jan', [150, 200, 50,150, 200, 50,150, 200, 50, 150, 200, 50,150, 200, 50,150, 200, 50,150, 200, 50,150, 200, 50])]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(sales)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. Can you edit the question with your `matplotlib` and `pandas` version and create a [mcve]?

Comment: Still not reproducible. `casa_consumo_h` is undefined. Is this problem specific to a datetime index?

Comment: it is working now @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: Running the code, I get [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4XBk.png). This seems to be the desired output, is it not?

Comment: weird because I tried in jupyter notebook and spyder and this is not my result

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest you must have added a extra bracket. It only works if you do this.

Comment: I did not add or remove anything from the code.

Comment: ok, this happened to me in both Jupyter notebook and Spyder. Only after I added an extra [ colors ] started to work properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.plot(y='Jan',kind='bar',edgecolor='none',figsize=(16,8),linewidth=2, color=[colors])
```

it was missing double[[]]